# HTML5 - Data final menor que a data inicial

Tags: html5

Possuo dois campos:

```
<input type="date" id="data_inicial" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" disabled>
<input type="date" id="data_final">
```

O primeiro campo, tenho a data inicial preenchida e setada como desabilitado. 
O segundo campo, tenho a data em aberto.

Nota: Estou usando apenas type date do HTML5, não estou usando nenhum tipo de validador.

Como faço para que o segundo campo, sempre seja MAIOR do que o primeiro? Há alguma regra que eu possa acrescentar ao campo para buscar a data a partir somente da data de inicio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta utilizar o atributo `min`:

```
<input type="date" id="data_final" min="<?= date("Y-m-d") ?>">
```

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```html
<input type="date" id="data_final" min="2017-07-01">
```

Como comentado, se a necessidade for que a data final seja sempre maior que a inicial, basta adicionar um dia à mesma:

```
<?php

$data_inicial = date("Y-m-d");
$data_final = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data_inicial . ' +1 day'));

?>

<input type="date" id="data_inicial" value="<?= $data_inicial ?>" disabled>
<input type="date" id="data_final" min="<?= $data_final ?>">
```

> **Atenção:** Vale lembrar que se o formulário for submetido, o campo `data_inicial` não será enviado, pois está definido como `disabled`. Se a intenção é submetê-lo junto, configure-o como `readonly`, assim a edição do valor também não será possível, mas será enviado junto com o formulário.

Comment: Isto seria o correto, porém, podemos adicionar +1 na data, para que seja o próximo dia, e não o mesmo dia. Mas não vejo necessidade... Sua resposta foi exata ao que preciso.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, como eu faria a data atual +1? Para deixarmos para o próximo dia? Pode acrescentar em sua resposta? Obrigado.

Comment: @AndréBaill feito.

Comment: Sobre o disabled, é isso mesmo, porque eu trato de outra forma quando eu recebo o post :) De mais a mais, é isso mesmo Anderson, grato.

Comment: Já testou em todos os navegadores?

Comment: Não, mas o suporte a HTML 5 já é bem consolidado. Não acredito que deve existir algum problema mais sério em relação a isso. Link do [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime).

Comment: Tenho IE11, Edge 14,  Firefox 54, e não funciona. Será que meus navegadores estão bugados? Nos seus funcionam?

Comment: aqui só Chrome e Opera

Comment: Tentei isso, mas não funciona. Mesmo atribuindo via js, o campo não pe preenchido com a data do dia.

Answer (score 2):

Com a HTML5 a vida dos desenvolvedores provavelmente ficou mais simples através das introduções dos novos tipos de inputs. Porém, como todos os outros recursos da HTML5, o suporte ainda é muito limitado pela parte dos browsers. Por isso devemos ter cautelas ao usar esse novos recursos. Por exemplo, o input type date só funciona no Chrome e Opera.

Isto exposto acho útil apresentar uma alternativa que funcione em todos os Navegadores atuais.

### Alternativa que funciona em todos os Navegadores

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#data_final").datepicker({
 dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
 dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
 dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
 dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
 monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
 monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
 nextText: 'Próximo',
 prevText: 'Anterior',
 minDate: 1 

 });

});
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="date" id="data_final" />
```

### OBS

1. O formato da data é dd/mm/aaaa e pode ser setada na linha  `dateFormat: dd/mm/yy`
2. A aceitação de datas a partir do dia seguinte ao atual é setado nessa linha `minDate: 1` 
   Zero para aceitar a partir da data atual inclusive. Aceita valores negativos.

> Embora o Chrome domine amplamente as estatísticas de Navegadores de Internet mais usados com 75.7% em abril/2017 não devemos desprezar a parcela restante.
>    [**Fonte**](https://www.w3schools.com/Browsers/default.asp)

Documentação:

- [Datepicker | jQuery U](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)
- [Download Builder | jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download/)